# Diplaying multiple names from ListView into a single view

Tags: android, listview, view

I'm using a ListView to display an array of names. 
Code for it looks like this:

```
public class Imenik extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  final String[] seznam = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.seznam_array);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, seznam));

  final ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            if ("Baj And".equals(seznam[position]))
            { Intent i = new Intent(Imenik.this,Bajzelj.class); startActivity(i); lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position); }   
            else if ("Bes Jaz".equals(seznam[position]))
            { Intent i = new Intent(Imenik.this,Bajzelj.class); startActivity(i); }             
        }
      });
    } 

}
```

Now I would like to display this names into just one view (Only one name per choice) with different data (one xml file).

```
public class Bajzelj extends Activity {

int position;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    this.setTitle("Interni imenik");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String[] seznam = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.seznam_array);

    {
    if  ("Bajželj Andrej".equals(seznam[position]))
    {
        TextView ime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ime);
        ime.setText("And Baj");
        TextView telefon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefon);
        telefon.setText("Telefon: +386 1 476");
        TextView gsm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobitel);
        gsm.setText("GSM: +386 41 ");
        TextView skype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skype);
        skype.setText("Skype: ba+");
        TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        email.setText("E-pošta: and.baj@som.org");
        ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika);
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.andbaj);          
    }
    else if ("Bes Jan".equals(seznam[position]))
    {
        TextView ime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ime);
        ime.setText("Jan Bes");
        TextView telefon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefon);
        telefon.setText("Telefon: +386 1 4");
        TextView gsm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobitel);
        gsm.setText("GSM: +386 41 75");
        TextView skype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skype);
        skype.setText("Skype: sf");
        TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        email.setText("E-pošta: Jan.Besej.si");
        ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika);
        slika.setImageResource(R.drawable.besjaz);          
    }       
    }  
}
```

}

Is it possible to display them like this? I'm not a programmer so I'm having a lot of troubles with this one. I know that I should check for position somehow but I don't know how to do this?

Thanks in advance to anybody who is willing to help me.

Comment: I am not clear with the question... Can you please specify more clearly. You are displaying data in a list view from an array. When clicked on each item what you want to perform...?

Comment: I'm trying to do this - When I choose a name from listView I would like it to open an Activity Bajzelj. And then depending on the name I choose I would like to fill it with personal date (each person has different data). For activity Bajzelj I would like to use just one xml that has empty TextViews and ImageView.

Comment: Ok, I understood your requirement. where you are getting problem.. In preparing xml file or in fetching particular data.

Comment: In fetching particular data. It always shows just the first persons data and even when I choose second person from listview it show the same data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this more effective way.

1. Use a Map object to store individual user data.
2. Add these map objects to the List.
3. Use custom adapter to display in the ListView.
4. Whenever user clicks on particular list item, pass its position in intent.
5. get position from Bundle and retrieve the particular user data from map of List.
6. display all the data of the user.

If you want a code snippet send me the user data fields i can send you the code snippet.

here is the code.

Test.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Test extends Activity{
    public Map<String,Object> userData;
    public static List<Object> userList;

    String[] name = {"name_one","name_two","name_three","name_four","name_five"};
    String[] lastName = {"lastName_one","lastName_two","lastName_three","lastName_four","lastName_five"};
    String[] telephoneNumber = {"telephoneNumber_one","telephoneNumber_two","telephoneNumber_three","telephoneNumber_four","telephoneNumber_five"};
    String[] mobileNumber = {"mobileNumber_one","mobileNumber_two","mobileNumber_three","mobileNumber_four","mobileNumber_five"};
    String[] skypeUserName = {"skypeUserName_one","skypeUserName_two","skypeUserName_three","skypeUserName_four","skypeUserName_five"};
    String[] email = {"email_one","email_two","email_three","email_four","email_five"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        userList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            userList.add(getUserData(i));
        }       
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        ListCustAdapter adapter = new  ListCustAdapter(this, userList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);     
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Test.this,Test2.class); 
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });     
    }

    public Map<String,Object> getUserData(int i){
        userData = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        userData.put("name", name[i]);
        userData.put("lastName", lastName[i]);
        userData.put("telephoneNumber", telephoneNumber[i]);
        userData.put("mobileNumber", mobileNumber[i]);
        userData.put("skypeUserName", skypeUserName[i]);
        userData.put("email", email[i]);
        return userData;
    }
}
```

Test2.java

```
package com.test;    
import java.util.Map;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test2 extends Activity{
    TextView name,lname,phono,cellno,sky,email;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test2);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        phono = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.telephoneNumber);
        cellno = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);
        sky = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.skypeUserName);
        email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);

        name.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("name"));
        lname.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("lastName"));
        phono.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("telephoneNumber"));
        cellno.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("mobileNumber"));
        sky.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("skypeUserName"));
        email.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("email"));

    }
}
```

ListCustAdapter.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListCustAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public Activity context;    
    private List<Object> list;

    public ListCustAdapter(Activity context, List<Object> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;       
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText((String) ((Map<String, Object>) list.get(position)).get("name"));
        return tv;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

  <ListView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id = "@+id/list"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

test2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/name"/>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/last_name"/>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/telephoneNumber"/>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/mobileNumber"/>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/skypeUserName"/>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/email"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Test"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".Test2"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then run and enjoy......!

Comment: Thank a code snippet would be just what I need. User data fields are: Name & Last name, Telephone number, mobile number, skype user name, Email.

Comment: @user925185 from where you are getting these data..? from an array for each field or some other means..?

Comment: I put them myself in. I have a function for each person that contains all the data for that person. I just need to figure out how to remeber the intents decision (which name I pick) and open the right one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I owe you a couple of beers :) ... There is only thing that isn't working, a problem with userList in lines - name.setText((String)((Map<String,Object>)Test.userList.get(position)).get("name"));

Comment: I have tested it on my system everything is working fine... are you getting any error...?

Comment: Yes I'm getting an error with userList as I described above. And Eclipse is only offering me a solution: Rename in file. So application isn't going thrue.

Comment: I'm getting an error in Test2.java file with these two things Test.userList. - after I import junit.framework.Test; -> Test problem is resolved and I get notice that .userList - "userList cannot be resolved or is not a filed" ... so I can't compile this project because Eclipse won't let me until there are mistakes in it.

Answer (score 1):

The way in which you are passing the ID to the new activity is strange.  Try using this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Imenik.this,Bajzelj.class); 
i.putExtra("id", id);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, once you're in your Bajzelj activity, get the id like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
long _id = bundle.getLong("id");
```